# A programmign language for real-time 3D intensive graphics that doesn't use semicolons

Tags: c++, c, desktop-client

I want something like the power of C/C++ but I hate semicolons.

Is there some language I can use that doesn't use them and is similar to performance to the C or C++ languages for a desktop app that uses a heavy 3D simulation in real time?

Comment: what type of 3d simulations? what is the format of the input?

Comment: use an editor that automatically adds but hides semicolons

Comment: @jitter I hate to look at semicolons but C++ compiler needs them. This type of thing just adds problems down the line. I would prefer something like Crystal where you don't need semicolons at all.

Comment: hate of semicolons seems like a small reason to find a different language

Comment: @depperm everybody's different. to me it is a deal breaker.

Comment: Visual Basic.NET immediately comes to mind, it has no semicolons and can use every C# library and 3D engine on it. Python could also be an option that meets the requirements, although I'm not sure on performance of either.

Comment: @depperm: if he had asked for a language that was elegant, or a language that prioritized developer experience, people would have complained that it wasn't "objective".  Focusing on one "objective" characteristic solves that problem, and perhaps there is a correlation between language designers who care about DX and those who avoid semi-colons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Julia](https://julialang.org) language comes to mind.

It was designed to be [fast](https://julialang.org/benchmarks/)
[image]

It doesn't require semicolons, and if you implement something like [threejs](https://juliapackages.com/p/threejs) you can do additional 3d simulation, beyond the data visualization and plotting that comes has official support (3d is an option)

---

Another language that is relatively fast without semicolons is [go](https://go.dev).

There are [3d game engines](https://github.com/g3n/engine) written in go so it is possible to get 3d visualization

---

While comparing language speeds I stumbled on [v lang](https://vlang.io) (comparable to go), which also doesn't require semi colons. Comes with a [cross platform UI library](https://github.com/vlang/ui) and their [android example](https://github.com/vlang/vab) has 3d graphics, I'm assuming this could be used for 3d visualization

Comment: Looks cool. I will take a look at Julia.

Comment: @fegax please take a look at V too, it's quite amazing!